# Auto Detect Last Paragraph and Pass to Macro

Tags: macros, line-breaking, paragraphs

The MWE below produces the desired results:

> [image]

via the `\ProcessLastPara{}` which applies a desired `\parshape` to the given (*last*) paragraph.

### Questions:

The MWE below required me to manually identify *both* the start and end of the last paragraph so it could be passed on to the `\ProcessLastPara{}` macro.

1. Is it possible to achieve the effect of `\ProcessLastPara{<text>}` by simply identifying the beginning of the last paragraph.  That is, can I change the call to `\SetMyText` to be of the form:

   ```
   \SetMyText{%
      Other Text... 

      \LastParaBeginsHere
      Last Para Text%
   }%
   ```

   so that `\LastParaBeginsHere` invokes`\ProcessLastPara{Last Para Text}`.

   This would need some error checking to make sure that `\LastParaBeginsHere` really was indeed the last paragraph defined by `\SetMyText`.
2. Is it possible to auto detect where the last paragraph begins and ends so that I do not need to manually invoke `\ProcessLastPara{}` and identify the text of the last paragraph?

### Notes:

- This needs to work for the case where the text is defined in a macro before it is typeset.
- The solution of `\def\LastParaBeginsHere{\LastParShape}` won't work as I need to process the last paragraph text to determine the appropriate `\parshape` to apply.  That is, this is a 2 step process, the details of which are not included here to simplify the test case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\@MyText}{}
    \newcommand{\SetMyText}[1]{\def\@MyText{#1}}%
    \newcommand*{\OutputMyText}{\@MyText}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\LastParShape}{%
    \parshape 5
    0.10\hsize 0.80\hsize
    0.15\hsize 0.70\hsize
    0.20\hsize 0.60\hsize
    0.25\hsize 0.50\hsize
    0.30\hsize 0.40\hsize
}%


\newcommand*{\ProcessLastPara}[1]{%
    \LastParShape
    #1}%

\begin{document}
\SetMyText{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    \ProcessLastPara{%
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}%
}%
%% ----------------
\OutputMyText%
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want the para indent on the first line of your triangle, I cancelled it out (not quite correctly) in my answer but I could remove it to get the same shape that you and egreg show...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Removing indentation of the last para is preferrable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\@MyText}{}
    \newcommand{\SetMyText}[1]{\def\@MyText{#1\LastParShape\par}}%
    \newcommand*{\OutputMyText}{\@MyText}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\LastParShape}{%
    \parshape 5
    \dimexpr0.10\hsize-\parindent\relax \dimexpr0.80\hsize+\parindent\relax
    0.15\hsize 0.70\hsize
    0.20\hsize 0.60\hsize
    0.25\hsize 0.50\hsize
    0.30\hsize 0.40\hsize
}%



\begin{document}
\SetMyText{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.%
}%
%% ----------------
\OutputMyText%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't even need egreg's hat.

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this? You can specify the `\parhsape` _after_ the paragraph (ie, _after_ the `#1` in `\SetMyText`)?  However, this won't work as per second point in the _Notes_. I need the content of the last paragraph to be passed to `\ProcessLastPara{}` as a parameter so that I can determine the correct `\parshape` to apply.

Comment: @PeterGrill I saw that note but decided just to answer the question as asked, as I wanted to demonstrate this (which uses a few orders of magnitude fewer macro expansions than egreg's:-) (you could of course add a `\noindent` to the code in your question and egreg's answer to get the full length top row.

Comment: @PeterGrill I fixed the first line parshape (only needed in this answer as it's not too late to change the parshape but it is too late to use `\noindent` which could otherwise be added at the start of the para, so I adjust the parshape to account for the parindent here

Comment: Yes, I generally prefer non-expl3 answer as I can somewhat make sense of those, but can't use this particular answer myself as it does not allow me to compute the `\parshape` based on the content. But still several new things for me here. So, in general, is applying the `\parshape` _after_ the paragraph is ok?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very nice and concise answer, but I'm really confused by putting the `\LastParShape` after `#1`. I wish you would have time to explain more about it.

Comment: @javadr paragraph settings, whether `\parshape` or `\centering` etc use the settings in force at the _end_ of the paragraph, which is why you often see on this site warnings that `{\centering hello}` does not center as the settings are discarded but `{\centering hello\par}` does center, as does `{\noindent hello\centering\par}` setting the parshape is the same, it sets the linebreaking but is not consulted until tex starts linebreaking which is at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: @PeterGrill are you sure you can't determine the parshape to apply using a similar technique? You can get hold of the number of normal lines in the last paragraph what else do you need from the first run?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Really appreciate your concern. That was amazing!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Hmmm. Yeah, I could probably get the required info, but would require that I typeset the entire content again. Where as if I could get just the last para as a separate parameter, I could determine the `\parshape` from that and they typeset it. That may be a minor issue, let me try...

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy with `expl3`: collect the text, split it at `\par`, then detach the last paragraph and typeset it separately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetMyText}{s+m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_peter_mytext_seq { \par } #2
   }
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_peter_mytext_seq { \par } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_new:N \l_peter_mytext_seq
\tl_new:N \l_peter_mytext_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\OutputMyText}{}
 {
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_peter_mytext_seq \l_peter_mytext_tl
  \seq_use:Nn \l_peter_mytext_seq { \par } \par
  \LastParShape \l_peter_mytext_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\LastParShape}{%
    \parshape 5
    0.10\hsize 0.80\hsize
    0.15\hsize 0.70\hsize
    0.20\hsize 0.60\hsize
    0.25\hsize 0.50\hsize
    0.30\hsize 0.40\hsize
}

\begin{document}

\SetMyText{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
}

\OutputMyText

\end{document}
```

[image]