# How to get raggedright in tabular*?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to make a table with three columns of paragraphs, each in raggedright.  I can only make it work for the first two columns.  If I try to add `>{\raggedright}`, as in the commented-out line below, I get the following error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\fox{The quick brown fox jumps.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{%
  >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}%
  >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}%
  p{1.5in}}
%  >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}} % doesn't work in 3rd column
  \fox & \fox & \fox \\
  \fox & \fox & \fox
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `tabular*` with a fixed target width (here: 5in), you should add the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` at the start of the second argument of the `tabular*` environment.

Comment: Thanks, Mico.  I fixed the MWE to use tabular (the MWE was hacked down from an attempt to figure this out, which itself was hacked down from the original tabular* I was trying to include in a document).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use `\tabularnewline`, than you not need `\arraybackslash` for restoring meaning of `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\fox{The quick brown fox jumps.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\raggedright}p{1.5in}}}%
  \fox & \fox & \fox    \tabularnewline
  \fox & \fox & \fox
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**off-topic:** if you define width of all columns in table, than you not need to define table width with use `tabular*` environment, since it is determined by column widths. exception  is, if you like to add `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` by which you spread columns over prescribed table width.

Comment: Accepted this solution, since it explains my problem (\\ getting redefined).  Not sure I don't prefer \arraybackslash though, since it allows the shorter \\ in each row.

Answer (score 19):

Add `\arraybackslash` after `\raggedright`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\fox{The quick brown fox jumps.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{5in}{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}}% does work in 3rd column :)
  \fox & \fox & \fox \\
  \fox & \fox & \fox
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can shorten the code a bit by repeating the same column 3 times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\fox{The quick brown fox jumps.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{5in}{%
    *{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}}}%
  \fox & \fox & \fox \\
  \fox & \fox & \fox
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with use only  `p` column type in table i don't see why op use `tabular*` environment (which width is different than width of columns width). better is use ordinary `tabular` ...

Comment: @Zarko In general I agree, in this particular case the widths are surprisingly well choosen. Taking the intercolumn spaces into account, the sum is only off by 0.003 inch

Answer (score 3):

You can also put `\raggedright` after `p`. I've just used it for the last column but it would be OK with the other columns. For more details see the descriptions mentioned by @DavidCarlisle in [Auto Detect Last Paragraph and Pass to Macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464468/auto-detect-last-paragraph-and-pass-to-macro/464479#comment1168982_464479).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\fox{The quick brown fox jumps.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{5in}{%
  >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}%
  >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}%
  p{1.5in}<{\raggedright}}
%  >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}} % doesn't work in 3rd column
  \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[1] \\
  \fox & \fox & \fox
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that does not work in general, it assumes there is only one paragraph in the cell and no blank line at the ned, and no display math