# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr and cannot see any extra alignment tabs - the output is wrong

Tags: longtable, landscape

I am doing this long table in a landscape environment with wrapped text. Everything works fine for the first data row in the table but once I start adding the second row, I get the error "extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr". The issue I copied from the correct row and changed the content only i.e. I cannot see how there is extra alignment and reviewed and cannot find the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[]{anysize}
\marginsize{.8in}{0.8in}{0.8in}{0.8in} % mine

% \makeatletter
% \newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[]{p{0.75in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{1in}p{1.5in}p{1.5in}p{2.5in}}
\caption[My table-optional caption in list of tables]{Table-caption\label{longtable}} \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Optional at the top of the table, simply remove line if not needed} \\
Paper & 
Country & 
Idea & 
Topic &
Data &
Methodology &
Results                                                                                 \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}                                                                  \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Optional at the top of every other page, simply remove line if not needed} \\
Paper & 
Country & 
Idea & 
Topic &
Data &
Methodology &
Results                                                                                 \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\raggedright A &
\raggedright Be or not to be that is a problem &
\raggedright Cool to see you today man &
\raggedright Do it your self I don't care &
\raggedright Eat all your food, otherwise we are not going the park &
\raggedright Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to you &
\raggedright Gurious at me why? did I something wrong to youGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG OKay Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG ok \\
\raggedright A &
\raggedright Be or not to be that is a problem &
\raggedright Cool to see you today man &
\raggedright Do it your self I don't care &
\raggedright Eat all your food, otherwise we are not going the park &
\raggedright Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to you &
\raggedright Gurious at me why? did I something wrong to youGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG OKay Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG ok \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\raggedright` command redefines `\\ ` so it no longer works as a row break in tabulars, and so what follows is all treated as one row. You can either add `\arraybackslash` after all the `\raggedright`s to change it back, or you can load the ragged2e package and use `\RaggedRight` instead.

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467119/how-to-get-raggedright-in-tabular) for more info.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Off-topic: Your code is quite fragile, in the sense that the document class option `landscape` would have no effect at all but for the fact that the `graphicx` package is loaded, which does absolutely nothing purposeful in your document but, fortuitously, does give meaning to the `landscape` option. I think you're better off loading the `geometry` package with the options `landscape` and `margins=0.8in` -- and, conversely, not loading the `anysizes` package and omitting the directive `\marginsize{.8in}{0.8in}{0.8in}{0.8in}`. Loading the `graphicx` package would be optional.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for the suggestion, finally solved.

Comment: @Mico, Thanks for the suggestions. Just to clarify, it's a small portion of the a thesis and was testing to get the table right

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to have `\raggedright` apply to all cells' contents, you might as well modify the `p` column type so that `\raggedright` applies automatically. I suggest you load the `array` and `ragged2e` packages and then run

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
```

in the preamble. If you do *not* want to permit hyphenation of long words in the cells, you could run

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

You may then get rid of all subsequent `\raggedright` directives (and greatly declutter the code) by executing

```
\begin{longtable}{P{0.75in}P{0.5in}P{0.5in}P{1in}P{1.5in}P{1.5in}PO{2.5in}}
```

---

A full MWE (mininum working example), which also employs the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[landscape,letterpaper,margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,     % for \newcolumntype macro
            ragged2e,  % for \RaggedRight macro
            booktabs,  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
            longtable} % for longtable environment
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % disable full justification

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} l *{2}{P{0.75in}} P{1in} *{2}{P{1.5in}} P{2.5in} @{}}

%% headers and footers

\caption[My table-optional caption in list of tables]{Table-caption\label{longtable}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Optional at the top of the table, simply remove line if not needed} \\[0.5ex]
Paper & 
Country & 
Idea & 
Topic &
Data &
Methodology &
Results \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\ \addlinespace
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Optional at the top of every other page, simply remove line if not needed} \\[0.5ex]
Paper & 
Country & 
Idea & 
Topic &
Data &
Methodology &
Results \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\small (continued on next page)} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table

A &
Be or not to be that is a problem &
Cool to see you today man &
Do it your self I don't care &
Eat all your food, otherwise we are not going the park &
Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to you &
Gurious at me why? did I something wrong to youGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG OKay Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? \\
\addlinespace
B &
Be or not to be that is a problem &
Cool to see you today man &
Do it your self I don't care &
Eat all your food, otherwise we are not going the park &
Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to you &
Gurious at me why? did I something wrong to youGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGG OKay Furious at me why? did I do something wrong to youGGFurious at me why? \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Mico. I am completely new to latex and your example is exactly what I want.

Comment: I'd really appreciate one more thing. So this will be a very long table with a lot of text. I want to reduce the font size (I did that using \footnotesize}, but I also need to reduce the spacing between lines in the table, I tried to adjust given other solutions but things go crazy. If you could edit your solution to add this, that will be great.

Comment: @MKali - If you issue the directive `\footnotesize` (for a 20% linear reduction in font size) *before* `\begin{longtable}{...} ...`, the amount of vertical spacing between lines in the table cells will be reduced automatically as well. I would strong recommend *against* reducing the interline spacing by some brute force method, as doing so has the potential to render the text well-nigh illegible -- and downright unpleasant to even look at. To truly save on vertical space, you should adjust the relative column widths so that the widest columns are the ones that contain the most text.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification